# Displaying datarows underneath each other

Tags: c#, datatable, console-application

How can I loop through a datatable so that the rows display neatly underneath one another,row by row.

what I have tried is the following but like this all the data displays in one column.

```
foreach (DataRow row in myTopTenData.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn col in myTopTenData.Columns)
                {
                    Console.Write(row[col].ToString() + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Move your `Console.WriteLine();` to the outer loop. And try to use "\t" as a delimiter. Will be better visually. But that too wont help if the lengths of string will vary a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (DataRow row in myTopTenData.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in myTopTenData.Columns)
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0, -10}", row[col].ToString()));

        Console.WriteLine();
     }
```

`string.Format"{0, -10}"` will help you to align your columns (use negative values for a left alignment, positive for a right alignement, and of course 10 is an arbitrary value).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little Linq query and `String.Join`:

```
var allFields = myTopTenData.AsEnumerable()
      .Select(r => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, r.ItemArray));
string allFieldsLines = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, allFields);

Console.Write(allFieldsLines);
```

Here's the non-Linq version with a loop:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myTopTenData.Rows)
    Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, row.ItemArray) + Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try with this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in myTopTenData.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn col in myTopTenData.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write(row[col].ToString() + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Ok..There was a doubt on understanding the question.