# Displaying data of data table

Tags: c#, datatable, console-application

I want to display values or write them to a text file that it is written as such from a data set

```
ColumnID  columnName ColumnFamilyName
ValueOne  ValueTwo  ValueThree  
ValueThree  ValueFour  ValueFive
ValueSix  ValueSeven  ValueEight
```

I have done this which does not do the trick

```
foreach (DataRow row in myTopTenData.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                foreach (DataColumn col in myTopTenData.Columns)
                {
                    Console.Write(row[0].ToString() + " ");

                }
            }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: are you missing row[col]

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14376412/284240) ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter not exactly, she wants the values to be displayed differently

Comment: Just restructured the same question a bit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I still can't post a comment but here is a quick answer:

```
 foreach(DataRow row in myTopTenData.Rows)
 { 
     string ID  = row["ColumnID"].ToString();
     string Name= row["columnName"].ToString();
     string FamilyName= row["ColumnFamilyName"].ToString();    
 }
```

Make sure to check for `null` values when retrieving the data

Answer (score 12):

Assuming that myTopTenData is a DataTable then you loop on rows of a datatable in this way

```
foreach (DataRow row in myTopTenData.Rows)
{
     Console.WriteLine();
     for(int x = 0; x < myTopTenData.Columns.Count; x++)
     {
          Console.Write(row[x].ToString() + " ");
     }
}
```

Of course this snippet should be taken only as a trivial example.
You need to consider null values and a robust error checking.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Datagrid to display your DataTable like this :

in WPF :

```
datagrid.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new System.Windows.Data.Binding { Source = dt});
```

in winform :

```
datagrid.DataSource(datatable);
```