# How to save data into SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET MVC application. I need to get name and surname from user then I need to save it into my database.

I coded all necessary parts. When I enter the name and surname, the program correctly saves name and surname into the database (I checked it from SQL Server Management Studio), but I cannot see them on screen.

This is my corresponding index view.

```
@model System.Data.DataTable

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td> @Model.Rows [i][1] </td>
            <td> @Model.Rows [i][2] </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
<hr>
<a href="@Url.Action("Create","Renter")">Add Person</a>
```

`Index` action method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DataTable peopletbl = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person", sqlcon);
            sqlDa.Fill(peopletbl);
        }

        return View(peopletbl);
    }
```

Program produces these lines:

[wrong output](https://imgur.com/QNLkRRB)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376828/displaying-data-of-data-table

Comment: Hi, you need to first cast to your model (Person - each properties)  before return.

Comment: @AsifRaza can you give me example please I did not understand what you indicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
            //simulating data 
            DataTable peopletbl = new DataTable("Person");
            peopletbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            peopletbl.Columns.Add("SurName", typeof(string));

            DataRow row = peopletbl.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = "Alan";
            row["SurName"] = "Turing";

            peopletbl.Rows.Add(row);
            //until now, you already have the data    

            //at the view.....
            //just use index properly
            foreach (DataRow iRow in peopletbl.Rows)
            {
                var name = iRow["Name"];
                var surName = iRow["SurName"];
            }
```

Comment: If you could leave some additional text explaining your answer, it's generally better received than just dumping code with no comments.

Comment: @gilliduck you are correct. I put some comments inside the code. thank you!